# Throttle exception in Sharepoint Online _vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList/$count

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list of 7k records in my List (named Books). Once I reached 5k limit I designed my query as follows to get list items.

```
site_url/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Books')/items?$filter=Id ge 1 and Id le 5000 and Genre eq 'Fiction'
then
site_url/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Books')/items?$filter=Id ge 5001 and Id le 7000 and Genre eq 'Fiction'
```

Note: Omitted orderby & top parts in above queries

After being successful I've started to setup my counter query as follows.

```
site_url/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Books/$count?$filter=Id ge 1 and Id le 5000 and Genre eq 'Fiction'
site_url/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Books/$count?$filter=Id ge 5001 and Id le 7000 and Genre eq 'Fiction'
```

This case it fails with

```
An error occurred while processing this request.
```

**Doesn't count query work the same way as in list fetching?**

Even in smaller batch size 1-2000, 2001-4000, 4001-6000, 6001-7000, No luck.